# Well-definedness of commutation relation in commuting local Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, topological-order, locality, quantum-error-correction

I'm reading the famous paper by Haah: [Local stabilizer codes in three dimensions without string logical operators](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1962). In the last sentence of the introduction, he wrote:

> A logical operator is a Pauli operator possibly with infinite support that commutes with every generator. Since each generator is **local**, the commutation relation between the generator and an arbitrary Pauli operator is **well-defined**.

Why the locality guarantees the commutation relation is well-defined? Are there examples where removing the locality condition yields a not well-defined commutation relation between the logical operators and the generators of the Hamiltonian?